# Can I always interchange derivation and integration (of different differentials) of a definite integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Can I always do this if I identify the integrand as the derivative of another function?

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty} x^4e^{-ax} \text{dx}
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\text{d}^4}{\text{d}a^4} e^{-ax} \text{dx}
= \frac{\text{d}^4}{\text{d}a^4} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax} \text{dx}
= \frac{\text{d}^4}{\text{d}a^4} a^{-1}
= 24a^{-5}$

Is there a name for this?

Comment: Perhaps "differentiating under the integral sign" or the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

Comment: @Henry Is the Leibniz integral rule applicable here? Wouldn't I need a function $b(a) < \infty$ for the upper limit?